# Problem while creating 9 patch images

Tags: android, nine-patch

I am creating 9 patch images using draw9patch tool and  saving images with extension .9.png but when I am using created 9 patch images in app it is giving error.
But when I downloaded an 9 patch image from net & used in my same app it is working properly.

I am not getting what I am doing wrong .
Please Help

Comment: it is not showing any particular error but when I copy paste the 9 patch image to drawbale folder it shows image as erroneous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must be creating the 9-patch wrongly. I had also the same issue . You must be drawing the black patch on one side of image. Try to draw the black patch by dragging your mouse two side of image. I hope you can understand my words...........

Comment: Finally...It was not easy to understand your words.Thanks 
As I understood by creating so much times you should create continuous black pixels line not broken ones is it?

Comment: No you can create dotted line . You have to create the line at least two side of the image either top and left or right and bottom.

Comment: Line created at top & left edge working fine but line at right & bottom is showing same error

Answer (score 2):

Nine-patch images on Android must have transparent 1-pixel edge, and have opaque pixels in left-top border (1 pixel wide) specifying which part of image is stretched, and which do not.

More here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html#nine-patch